# Change line terminator

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can I force `StringReader.ReadLine()` (or alternative stream) to use `\n` instead of `\r\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation on [`StringReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readline.aspx):

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The resulting string does not contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the underlying string has been reached.

So, it will read lines terminated with `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n` by default. You do not need to override anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `StringReader.ReadLine` doesn't use only `"\r\n"` as line delimiter, it accepts either `"\r\n"`, `"\r"` or `"\n"`.